# GetProcessImageFileNameA "Access violation writing location" runtime error

Tags: c, winapi

I'm using the [`EnumProcesses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses) function to get all process IDs on the system. Then I iterate over each process ID and pass it to [`OpenProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) to get a process handle, which I then pass to [`GetProcessImageFileNameA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamea?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to get the process name.

Here's a code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

DWORD GetProcessName(DWORD processID, TCHAR lpFileName, DWORD nSize)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    DWORD pLength;
    
    // Get process handle
    hProcess = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,
        FALSE,
        processID
    );

    if ( !hProcess )
        return NULL;
    
    // Write process name to buffer
    if ( pLength = GetProcessImageFileNameA(hProcess, lpFileName, nSize) )
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return pLength;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}

int main(void)
{   
    DWORD processIDs[PROC_ID_SIZE], cbNeeded, cProcess;
    unsigned int i;

    // Get process IDs
    if ( !EnumProcesses(processIDs, sizeof(processIDs), &cbNeeded) )
        return 1;
    
    // Get process ID count
    cProcess = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
    printf("Number of Processes: %u | Size of Process Array: %d\n", cProcess, (int)sizeof(processIDs));

    // Get the process name of each process
    for (i = 0; i < cProcess; i++)
    {   
        if ( processIDs[i] != 0 )
        {   
            // The access violation is happening here
            TCHAR processName[MAX_PATH];
            GetProcessName(processIDs[i], processName, sizeof(processName));
            printf("Process name: %s\n", (char*)processName);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, but I get this runtime error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF985433338 (KernelBase.dll) in QuickSave.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000000000F8D0.
```

I have a suspicion it's because I'm declaring `processName` from outside of the function's scope. When I create another function and declare `processName` within that function's scope, it works. I'm not entirely sure why.

```
DWORD PrintProcessName(DWORD processID)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    TCHAR processName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD pLength;

    // Get process handle
    hProcess = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,
        FALSE,
        processID
    );

    if (!hProcess)
        return NULL;

    // Write process name to buffer and print it
    if ( pLength = GetProcessImageFileNameA(hProcess, processName, sizeof(processName)) )
    {
        printf("Process name: %s\n", (char*)processName);
        return pLength;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

I'm still learning C so I'm probably making a newbie mistake, but hopefully someone can help me make sense of what's going on here.

Comment: `DWORD GetProcessName(DWORD processID, TCHAR lpFileName, DWORD nSize)` The second parameter should be `TCHAR*` or I guess `LPTSTR` if you're gonna stick with `TCHAR` and Microsoft typedefs. `GetProcessName` also doesn't return a value in all cases.

Comment: *I have a suspicion* - not need do this. need take debugger and look exactly - where fail

Comment: You code doesn't even compile with MSVC 2019. There are `errors` and `warnings`. First fix **all** errors and warnings. If you don't understand an error or warning, then ask (by editing your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed your code. The main errors was bad declaration of `GetProcessName`, wrong size passed for processName size, incorrect `printf` format specification, function doesn't always return a value, missing error checks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

#define PROC_ID_SIZE 1000

DWORD GetProcessName(DWORD processID, TCHAR *lpFileName, DWORD nSize)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    DWORD pLength;

    // Get process handle
    hProcess = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
        FALSE,
        processID
    );

    if (!hProcess)
        return 0;

    // Write process name to buffer
    pLength = GetProcessImageFileNameW(hProcess, lpFileName, nSize);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return pLength;
}

int main(void)
{
    DWORD processIDs[PROC_ID_SIZE], cbNeeded, cProcess;
    unsigned int i;

    // Get process IDs
    if (!EnumProcesses(processIDs, sizeof(processIDs), &cbNeeded))
        return 1;

    // Get process ID count
    cProcess = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
    printf("Number of Processes: %u | Size of Process Array: %d\n", cProcess, (int)sizeof(processIDs));

    // Get the process name of each process
    for (i = 0; i < cProcess; i++)
    {
        if (processIDs[i] != 0)
        {
            // The access violation is happening here
            TCHAR processName[MAX_PATH];
            if (GetProcessName(processIDs[i], processName, sizeof(processName)/sizeof(processName[0])))
                printf("Process name: %ls\n", processName);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to fix the *real* issue, the one that's likely to cause an access violation. Make sure to read about the parameters that [GetProcessImageFileNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamew) expects.

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `GetProcessImageFileNameW()` expects a *character* count, not a *byte* count. Replace `sizeof(processName)` with `MAX_PATH`. Also, the 2nd `if` in `GetProcessName()` is redundant and should be removed: `DWORD pLength = GetProcessImageFileNameW(...); CloseHandle(hProcess); return pLength;` No `if` needed. Also, `GetProcessImageFileNameW()` does not need `PROCESS_VM_READ`, only `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` or better `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`. Don't ask for more rights than you really need.